# java while loops with strings

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am trying to make a loop that prints "*" as a string a certain number of times, but I can't get it to work. Everything in the main method was given to me and must be used. Everything else I added and I don't know if I am on the right track or not. The end result is suppposed to print "*" seven times horizontally. Then each time it adds a "*", adds one to count, and compares to see if count is greater than or equal to the value I set. Then if it is true it ends the loop and if not it repeats the loop until true. I just don't know how express this in code.

```
    public class LoopPractice
    {
        public String ast = "*";    

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            LoopPractice lp = new LoopPractice();
            System.out.println(lp.getAstWhile(7));
        }   

        public String getAstWhile()  
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (count <= 6)
            {
                System.out.print(count++);
            }
            return ast;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: When you call `lp.getAstWhile(7)` in the `println()` function, you're passing an argument but `getAstWhile()` doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a value "7" to a function that accepts no values, call lp.getAstWhile(); instead of lp.getAstWhile(7);

```
public String getAstWhile(int maxValue)
{ 
     int count = 0; 
     while (count < maxValue) 
     { 
         system.out.print(count++); 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Actually if you want it to print 7 times horizontally, change your getAstwhile to the following 

public String getAstWhile(int maxValue){
int count = 0;
while (count < maxValue)
{
system.out.print(count++);
}
}

Comment: If you want to add to your post, edit it. Also, uses code blocks when typing code.

Comment: No even in the comments. Surround code you want to be part of a sentence with back-ticks (to the left of the "1" key, same key as tilde).

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuffer.

```
public String getAstWhile()  
    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int count = 0;
        while (count <= 6)
        {
            buf.append('*');
            count++;
        } 
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

getAstWhile was not returning a String in your original code.

API documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html
Tutorial on StringBuffer:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_buffer.htm

Comment: I'm not sure, as a student, this OP will understand the code you provided. Plus, I'm sure the instructor will notice the degree of change.

Comment: Surely the student can look up the StringBuffer class. This is the correct and recommended way to build a string in Java.

Comment: I suggestion you provide links and comments to help the OP.

Comment: I added some references. I would however like to point out that if someone introduces a new class, concept etc. to a good student, the first thing that student should be doing is googling for more information. Spoonfeeding the student, especially on such a trivial home-work style quesiton is not a good idea.